# PHP Request Price for Selected Item

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a table that has the following ItemID, ItemName, and ItemPrice. I have a drop downmenu that lists out the names of the items by the ItemID from the database. Now I want to show, based on what is selected from the dropdown menu by the user, the price of that item.

Here is what I tried:

```
<?php
                include ("account.php");
                include ("connect.php");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $options ="";

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $options .= '<option value="' . $row["ItemID"] . '">' . $row["ItemName"] . '</option>';
                }

                echo '<select name="ItemName">' . $options . '</select>';

                $getPrice = "SELECT ItemPrice FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = '$options' ";
                $getPrice = mysql_query($getPrice);
                $getPrice = mysql_result($getPrice, 0);

                echo '<label for="Price">Price: </label>';
                echo "$getPrice";
            ?>
```

It shows the items in the drop down menu but no matter what I select, I can't get the price to show. I am new to this whole PHP show and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getPrice = "SELECT ItemPrice FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = '$options' ";
```

This is where the problem lies. The $options variable contains a html text with the different options, but PHP has no understanding of this. The variable does NOT contain the id of the item the user is going to select.

You need a  to send the variable to another (or the same) PHP page.

You should read this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Can I use $_REQUEST["ItemName"] within the same HTML page? Would that get me the result?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".Items").change(function(){

                    window.location.href='?ItemID='+$(this).val();
            });
        });

      <script>
```

PHP code:

```
     <?php  

            include ("account.php");
            include ("connect.php");

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $options ="";

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $options .= '<option value="' . $row["ItemID"] . '">' . $row["ItemName"] . '</option>';
            }

            echo '<select name="ItemName" class="Items">' . $options . '</select>';


            $ItemID = $_GET['ItemID']; // retrive ItemID from querystring
            $getPrice = "SELECT ItemPrice FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = '$ItemID' ";
            $getPrice = mysql_query($getPrice);
            $getPrice = mysql_result($getPrice, 0);

            echo '<label for="Price">Price: </label>';
            echo "$getPrice";
        ?>
```

another method:

```
    echo '<select name="ItemName" onchange="ItemPrice(this)">' . $options . '</select>';
```

javascript:

```
     <script>
        function ItemPrice(d){
            window.location.href='?ItemID='+d.value;
        }
     </script>
```

**Note**: Please use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions (deprecated)

Comment: Did you add the $ItemID = $_GET['ItemID']; and select query update in inventory table

Comment: Yes, I did and I tried all the methods you posted but unfortunately, I'm not getting the result I want.

Comment: Can you open up Chrome debugging tools and see if there are any Javascript errors? That script should work but you'll need jQuery to get it going.

Comment: echo $getPrice = "SELECT ItemPrice FROM Inventory WHERE ItemID = '$ItemID' "; and check whether database has value and make your you got the $ItemID value

Comment: $getPrice is coming out empty.